# Throwing exception based on condition in before plugin

Tags: magento2, before-plugin, exception-error

I'm creating a `before plugin` for the class `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost`. In the `execute` method I want to throw an Exception based on certain condition but the plugin is showing output like this.

[image]

I want to print proper exception message in notification area like this.

[image]

Here is my Plugin Class

```
class EditPost {

        public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost $subject) {

            throw new \Exception('Exception trigger');
            return $subject;

        }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution using `around plugin`.

```
public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost $subject, $proceed) {

            if(true) { // for true condition
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('My custome Error');
                /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
            return $proceed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use your before plugin and use `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` for this.

```php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
 */
private $messageManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager)
{
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}

public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost $subject) {
    try {
        //your code
        throw new \Exception('Exception trigger');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

The important part is if you decide to throw an exception that you catch it. Then you can use the `Message\Manager` to display your desired message.

If you return `null` or as in your answer with the around plugin `$proceed()` keep in mind that the base method will be executed and it will still save the customer.

Comment: its not working this way e.g. if you want to restrict 'change_email'. With your solution this is not fulfill my requirement that's why I'm using around plugin

Comment: That is true if you want to restrict that. But it answers the question about the message maybe add that you want to restrict certain functionality in your question then a around plugin is the way to go.